# app engine python: populate structured property with json gives error

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

**Context**

I have the following data structure:

```
class Birthday(ndb.Model):
  day = ndb.IntegerProperty()
  month = ndb.IntegerProperty()
  year = ndb.IntegerProperty()

class User(ndb.Model):
  name = ndb.StringProperty()
  birthday = ndb.StructuredProperty(Birthday)
  # ... other properties
```

**Problem**

When I try to use the **populate()** method on an instance of User, it gives an error: expecting a Birthday instance instead of a dictionary of params.

If I remove the birthday property, everything works fine: the User instance is populated with the dictionary of params.

Shouldn't the populate() method recognize structured properties and automatically populate them as well?

Any clues?

Thanks

PS: The populate method could also use a forgiving mode on which it ignores unknown properties for which there are references on the params dictionary.

**>>Added comments**

I'm using a *generic REST Handler* which is *extended for* accessing and changing several data types. The extension has to define a method getModel() that returns the model class to access/manipulate. The model class has to implement a few methods, namely create(cls, params).

The POST handler parses params (sent by AngularJS using $resouce -- link below) the following way:

```
# inside the generic REST Handler
params = json.loads(self.request.body, object_hook=self.datetime_decoder) # parse json params
...
self.getModel().create(params) # invokes the create method of the
```

The model class implements the create method the following way:

```
@classmethod
def create(cls, params = None):
    obj = cls()
    if params:
        obj.update(**params)
        obj.put()
        return True, obj
    return False, None
```

The contents of the *JSON dict* are:

```
{"name":"Ana Matos","email":"ana.matos@nvd.com","phone":"+35196983465671","birthday":{"day":1,"month":0,"year":1980},"gender":"FEMALE","groups":["2012/2013"],"serviceProviderId":206133}
```

[JSON contens -- firefox screenshot](http://cl.ly/image/1o1e0W1H0R0L)

[AngularJS $resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource)

Answer (score 1):

Are you reporting a bug or requesting a feature?  The populate() method requires its parameter types to match the declared type of the property, which in this case is a Birthday instance.

It would help if you showed the contents of the JSON dict that you are passing to populate() (and exactly how you are passing it).

Possibly the solution is as simple as getting the 'birthday' value from the JSON dict and using it to create a Birthday instance.  But I would have to see your code to know for sure.

Comment: I've added additional info above. I'm looking for an automatic way of populating ndb model instances with json that works even when said instances have structured properties.

Comment: That's definitely a feature request.  Perhaps you want a _from_dict() that's the counterpart of the _to_dict() method?  When we added the latter we discussed adding _from_dict() but we couldn't think of a use case.  It seems you have one.  Would you mind filing a feature request in the NDB tracker?  http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/issues/list

Comment: _from_dict() seems to be it, as long as it works with Structured Properties (which could be nested). I'll fill out the feature request. [link to feature request](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-ndb-experiment/issues/detail?id=207&thanks=207&ts=1347490239)

Comment: The other thing I'm using is a 'forgiving' mode. It ignores keys on the dict that do not correspond to properties on the ndb.Model instance. This is good when the client 'pollutes' the original model with client-side specific data such as _selected or _edited properties.

Comment: Honestly, if you want a "forgiving" mode I think you should just bite the bullet and write it yourself.  It's not that hard (you could even use MyModel._properties to list the properties of your mode).  I prefer NDB to be strict in what it accepts, so as to catch programming errors early.

Comment: I already have. It was easy to implement. Nevertheless, I was thinking that if the populate() method had a 'forgiving' parameter which defaulted to False, it would force the programmer to explicitly override 'error detection'. This all about making it even easier to prototype python backends for JavaScript clients.

Comment: Can we get an update on this one please? The behaviour seems to have changed. If you have structured properties, arbitrarily nested and or repeated, you *can* set their properties by updating the model instance they're nested inside. If `x` is the container model instance, then `x.populate(**x.to_dict())` works, but is a no-op, and mutating `x.to_dict()` before passing it back in seems to work fine.

Comment: `^` I've been doing this to pass copies of nested db structs back and forth as JSON, no issues. I can mutate any attribute of the nested dicts that represent the nested model instances and updating the container model seems to trickle down. <bit worried as this is about to go into production>

Comment: `^` This seems to be creating new instances of the ndb models; if required properties are deleted from the update dict, it throws a `BadValueError: Entity has uninitialized properties...`.